# Ansible Playbook using mysql 1044, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'scm'"

Tags: mysql, ansible, rhel7

Trying to setup Cloudera Enterprise 5.16.x on Rhel 7.6. I'm trying to follow the following guide from https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-16-x/topics/install_cm_mariadb.html. I have written an ansible playbook for above commands. Whenever I'm trying to grant privileges to user.

```
GRANT ALL ON <database>.* TO '<user>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

Im getting the following error if i try using ansbile.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_mysql_db_payload_agOLmm/__main__.py", line 373, in main
    changed = db_create(cursor, db, encoding, collation)
  File "/tmp/ansible_mysql_db_payload_agOLmm/__main__.py", line 240, in db_create
    cursor.execute(query, query_params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'oozie'")

failed: [cloudera-node1.cisco.com] (item=oozie) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "ca_cert": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "collation": "",
            "config_file": "/root/.my.cnf",
            "connect_timeout": 30,
            "encoding": "utf8",
            "ignore_tables": [],
            "login_host": "localhost",
            "login_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "login_port": 3306,
            "login_unix_socket": null,
            "login_user": "root",
            "name": "oozie",
            "quick": true,
            "single_transaction": false,
            "state": "present",
            "target": null
        }
    },
    "item": "oozie",
    "msg": "error creating database: (1044, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'oozie'\")"
}
```

Here is sample ansible playbook main.yml under roles/management/task/main.yml

Sample main.yml

```
- name: install mariadb-server
  yum:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
  vars:
    packages:
      - mariadb-server
  tags: mariadb

- name: stop the mariadb service
  service:
    name: mariadb
    state: stopped
    enabled: yes
  tags: mariadb

- name: Take backup of the ib_lofile0 and ib_logfile1
  command: "{{ item }}"
  register: command_output
  ignore_errors: true
  with_items:
    - mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 /root/ib_logfile0.bkp
    - mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 /root/ib_logfile1.bkp
  tags: mariadb

- name: Copy my.conf to /etc/my.conf
  template:
    src: "{{role_path}}/templates/my.cnf"
    dest: /etc/my.cnf
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
    backup: yes
  tags: mariadb

- name: start the mariadb.service
  command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - systemctl enable mariadb.service
  tags: mariadb

- name: start the mariadb service
  service:
    name: mariadb
    state: started
    enabled: yes
  tags: mariadb

- name: Adds Python MySQL support on RedHat/CentOS
  yum: name=MySQL-python state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'
  tags: mysql

- name: Set the root password
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    user: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    host: localhost
    check_implicit_admin: yes
  tags: mysql

- name: Removes all anonymous user accounts
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    name: ''
    host_all: yes
    state: absent
  tags: mysql

- name: Secure the root user for IPV6 localhost (::1), localhost (127.0.0.1), localhost domain and server hostname domain
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    name: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    host: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "::1"
    - "127.0.0.1"
    - "localhost"
    - "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
  tags: mysql

- name: Removes the test database
  mysql_db:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    db: test
    state: absent
  tags: mysql

- name: Flushes the user priveleges
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    name: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    priv: "*.*:ALL"
    state: present
    check_implicit_admin: yes
  tags: mysql


- name: Create a list of databases with encoding as utf-8
  mysql_db:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
    encoding: utf8
  with_items:
    - "amon"
    - "scm"
    - "rman"
    - "metastore"
    - "nav"
    - "hue"
    - "navms"
    - "sentry"
    - "oozie"
  tags: mysql_db_create

- name: Dump all the database
  mysql_db:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    name: all
    state: dump
    encoding: utf8
    target: "{{ temp_folder }}/clouderadb.sql"
  tags: mysql_db_create

- name: Set mysql user privileges
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    name: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    priv: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    update_password: on_create
  with_items:
    - 'amon.*:ALL'
    - "scm.*:ALL"
    - "rman.*:ALL"
    - "metastore.*:ALL"
    - "nav.*:ALL"
    - "hue.*:ALL"
    - "navms.*:ALL"
    - "sentry.*:ALL"
    - "oozie.*:ALL"
  tags: mysql_db_create
```

When I connect to mysql database from cli. I see only amon database has access to root privileges.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS for 'root'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*B3AB897994763B468137496DD4FD8507F755DB55' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `amon`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'                                                      |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| amon               |
| hue                |
| metastore          |
| mysql              |
| nav                |
| navms              |
| oozie              |
| performance_schema |
| rman               |
| scm                |
| sentry             |
+--------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------+--------------------------+
| User | Host                     |
+------+--------------------------+
| root | %                        |
| root | 127.0.0.1                |
| root | ::1                      |
| root | cloudera-node1.cisco.com |
| root | localhost                |
+------+--------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue. Looks like a restriction specific to MariaDB on RDS. I've worked with MySQL on RDS as well and there I didn't have this problem.

Find more info here

https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant/issues/660

https://www.culturefoundry.com/cultivate/technology/creating-multiple-database-users-for-maria-db-rds/

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/duplicate-master-user-mysql/

This syntax fixed it for me.

```
  name              : "{{ item.value.DB_USER }}"
  priv              : '{{ item.value.DB_NAME }}.*:SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT,CREATE,DROP,INDEX,ALTER,LOCK TABLES,EXECUTE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,EXECUTE,TRIGGER,CREATE VIEW,SHOW VIEW,EVENT,REQUIRESSL'
  host              : "%"
  state             : "present"
  login_host        : "localhost"
```